# The Google Fit button in your YouTube link is not compliant with the Google fit branding guidelines

Tags: google-fit, google-fit-sdk, google-fit-api, google-fitness-api

Google says that login button is wrong.

"Sign-in Branding

The Google Fit button in your YouTube link is not compliant with the Google fit branding guidelines.

Please update the button so that it complies with the [Google Fit branding guidelines](https://developers.google.com/fit/branding)."

[image]

And the video itself: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bj2vDKhX5nU

What is this screen supposed to look like? Does somebody have examples of buttons that DID pass the review process? I did follow the branding guidelines to the best of my understanding, but it's still stuck.

EDIT: Should it actually be one button to activate Google Fit, and then another to request the permission for physical activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am currently going through the same process as you do. I think it has to do with the folowing:

- button background should be white or gray (maximum 5% black);
- use color Google Fit logo (see ther marketing guidelines page); keep it to the left side of the button, as it’s most common; mind the padding;
- maybe use Connect to Google Fit for the button text, which is one of their recommendations.

I will return with an update as soon as I hear from the Google team again.

Comment: Thanks, I will try these out and let you know also! I got email from Google pointing to this documentation: https://developers.google.com/identity/branding-guidelines#top_of_page

Do you think there should be separate button for signing in to google and then a another for granting Google Fit permission?

Comment: There are also these Google Fit guidelines: https://developers.google.com/fit/branding I tried following these and grabbed the button copy from there among with the copies.

Comment: I do not know why they suggest anything related to the Google Sign In button - that flow is completely unrelated imo. Even more, none of the apps that I use, connected to Google Fit, implement those rules (google fit branding). Check Strava, for example.

Comment: They first send an email saying it doesn't adhere to the Google Sign In button branding, but a few days later send out a new email saying it doesn't adhere to Google Fit. I made the suggested contrast and icon location changes and it seems they now approved the button.

Comment: Same here, with the advice above I managed to get the app approved.